# cluster analysis Hadoop, Map reduce environment

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, analysis, spss

we are currently trying to create some very basic [personas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persona#In_marketing) based on our user data base (few million profiles). The goal is to find out at this stage what the characteristics of our users are, for example what they look like and what they are looking for and to create several "typical" user profiles.

I believe the best way to achieve this would be to run a cluster analysis in order to find similarities among users.

The big roadblock however is how to get there. We are tracking our data in a Hadoop environment and I am being told that this could be potentially achieved with our tools.

I have familiarised myself with the theory of the topic and know that it can be done for example in SPSS (quite hard to use and limited to samples of large data sets).

The big question: Is it possible to perform a or different types of cluster analysis in a Hadoop environment and then visualise the results like in SPSS? It is my understanding that we would need to run several types of analysis in order to find the best way to cluster the data, also when it comes to distance measurements of the clusters.

I have not found any information on the internet with regards to this, so I wonder if this is possible at all, without a major programming effort (meaning literally implementing for example all the standard tools available in SPSS: Dendrograms, the different result tables and cluster graphs etc.).

Any input would be much appreaciated. Thanks.

Comment: As a starting point, look at mahout for Hadoop based clustering and other machine learning capabilities - http://mahout.apache.org/

Comment: Hi, Chris, much appreciated!! Will have a look. Thanks!